# Components based globally

Tags: ee2, channel, multiple-channels

Just a quick post to find out if something is possible or not within EE.

We have been looking at the easiest way of trying to make certain blocks of code within our sites global. What we are doing is setting up the right column  to show all the components that would be available across the site i.e. Twitter, Social Media, Relationships etc so the user can choose what they want in each page. Sort of similar way as Drupal works if you see where I am coming from.

I can set up checkboxes for Twitter and Social Media as they are not connected to channel fields but with Relationships you have to set up a channel field (generic-events or news-events etc) in each channel.

Is there anyway of not having to set up a channel field in every channel or maybe there is a module that is out there?

Hope this is clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: Have you looked at Low Variables (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables)? I'm not 100% clear what you mean about user-selected relationships.

Comment: Example of what I am after is where say I have a relationships channel field in the right column where you say select an event to show in any given page. I then want to be able to push that out across the site so you can do this in any template without having to add a new channel field in each channel field list. I am currently having to add a new channel field to each channel so it can show the relationship.

I think that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[Low Variables](http://www.devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-variables) is what you want. A lot of us use it on every project as it allows for global variables with a user-friendly (ie, client-friendly) interface.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will have a look and let you know how I get on.